# Thin and Bundler on Windows Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thin

Trying to get Thin working with Bundle on Windows, I know, major PITA
but anyways, I'm new to Thin and Bundle gem, I'm on Ruby 1.8.6 and
Rails 2.3.5 and trying to get someone else's app running on my laptop,
the app uses Thin and Bundle gem to install gems required. I noticed
that bundle created a .bundle folder under My Documents folder and put
all the gems there for the app. When I tried "thin run", it reported
'thin' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
program or batch file.

I check the environment path and it doesn't point to the .bundle
folder at all and I found there is a thin.bat in

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Bob\.bundle\ruby\1.8\bin
```

When I tried "C:\Documents and Settings\Bob.bundle\ruby\1.8\bin\thin"
start, it gave me another error

```
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:777:in
`report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem thin (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
    from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:211:in `activate'
from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1056:in `gem'
from C:/Documents and Settings/Bob/.bundle/ruby/1.8/bin/thin:18
```

I get the same error if I added "C:\Documents and Settings\Bob.bundle
\ruby\1.8\bin" to the env path. Anyone know I can get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those of you that are new to bundler gem (as I am), the command is

```
bundle exec thin start
```

Hope that helps someone else scratching their heads.